# p4 sync parallel on Linux giving "Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset." error

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, synchronization, perforce

I'm trying to improve perforce sync performance on Linux using the --parallel option, but keep getting the error repeated once for each thread I specify:

> Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.

If I set `P4PORT`, `P4USER`, `P4PASSWD` and `P4CLIENT` environment variables and then do a simple p4 sync, it works fine.  If I use the following command I get the error message 4 times (once for each thread):

```
p4 sync --parallel "threads=4,min=1,minsize=1"
```

If I specify the password as a global on the command line, I get the same:

```
p4 -P passwd sync --parallel "threads=4,min=1,minsize=1"
```

If I get the ticket first using `p4 login -p` and substitute that for the password in the sync command I get the same.

Comment: What if you use plain old "p4 login" so you have a ticket in your tickets file?

Comment: I'm writing a node app that interacts with Perforce.  Using environment variables is significantly simpler that doing an interactive login.

Comment: There was at least one bug that matched those symptoms, so I'd triple-check (with Tech Support's help if necessary) that you have the latest patches for both client and server executables in your system.

Comment: @IanW, did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: I'm still facing this exact same bug.